# Mysql Query Inner Join

Tags: mysql

Two Tables

tblEatables and tblConfirm_Eatables

**tblEatables**

```
Sno     Name  
1      Apples
2      Oranges
3      Papaya
4      Jackfruit
5      Pineapple
6      Mango
```

**tblConfirm_Eatables**

```
Eatbles_Id   Confirm_Status 
     1               0 
     2               1
     3               0
     4               0
```

Question 1

Why the Below Query Brings Repeated Record Sets

```
SELECT E.Name         
FROM Eatables E INNER JOIN 
Confirm_Eatables CE ON CE.Eatbles_Id != E.Sno
```

Why the Below Query brings all eatbles from the table though i used <>

```
SELECT E.Name         
FROM Eatables E INNER JOIN 
      Confirm_Eatables CE ON E.Sno != CE.Eatbles_Id
GROUP BY E.Name
```

**OP**

```
Name
Apples
Jackfruit
Mango
Oranges
Papaya
Pineapple
```

Comment: Duplication occurs because sno(2,3,4,5,6) does not equal eatables_id(1), sno(1,3,4,5,6) does not equal eatables_id(2) etc. This answers both questions.

Comment: Do you by any chance want to find out eatables not found in table confirm_eatables?

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović Yes

Comment: Than take a look at @ZaneBien's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is great example of different JOINs on the top of page
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_explicit_join_operations/page1.html

For me better to use = in join query and use after it EXCEPT. In your way:

```
  SELECT E.Name FROM Eatables 
                EXCEPT ALL
  SELECT E.Name FROM Eatables E INNER JOIN 
         Confirm_Eatables CE ON CE.Eatbles_Id = E.Sno
```

Comment: I think what you mean is `EXCEPT`, not `RESTRICT`. Even with `EXCEPT`, it wouldn't work as MySQL doesn't support that particular keyword.

Comment: EXCEPT surely, and "=" instead of "==". :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM tblEatables a
LEFT JOIN tblConfirm_Eatables b ON a.Sno = b.Eatables_Id
WHERE b.Eatables_Id IS NULL
```

Which will get all rows in `tblEatables` that aren't in `tblConfirm_Eatables`.

For a better understanding of how this works, see [**this link**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for a good visual guide to using joins in SQL; in particular, the fourth one down, where we use the `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` technique to retrieve all records in table A that have no match in table B.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this `E.Sno != CE.Eatbles_Id` condition in `WHERE` clause.

using `!=` operator in join will give you unexpected results.

Comment: using them in where clause will also cause unexpected results